# I didn't know what I should/was supposed to do

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, past-simple

Can 'should' be used in the past? I don't mean a regret here. I haven't found an answer on the Internet because all the explanations describe regrets.

> I didn't know what I **should/was supposed** to do

Comment: Both are fine, as would be *I didn't know what I should / was supposed to **have done***. Note that in your case we're pairing *[negated] **know + do***, but in other contexts it might be the ***same*** verb both sides of "should / was supposed to" - ***He didn't do what he was supposed to do***. In *that* case, most native speakers would "delete" the predictably-repeated ***do*** at the end (but there's no such "deletion" if it's "backshifted" to ***...to have done***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for your comment, but my question was rather about 'should' vs 'supposed to' and the difference between them if any. On the other hand, your comment made me think about the difference between 'do' and 'have done'. I feel that 'have done' expresses regret, but there's no regret here. It's about the speaker's thoughts back then, not about what they were supposed to have done but didn't. Am I right?

Comment: If you're actually only interested in the choice between ***should*** and ***[be] supposed to***, I don't see why your example context includes ***I didn't know***. I seems to me you could have just asked about the difference between  ***I should go*** and ***I am supposed to go***

Comment: @FumbleFingers please, read the question again. I asked whether it can be used in the past.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, there are lots of written instances of [*knew what he should **do***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22knew+what+he+should+do%22) as well as [*knew what he should **have done***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22knew+what+he+should+have+done%22) (the Past Tense versions of *I [didn't] know what I should **do / have done***). I'd say ***should*** is a "degenerate" verb that doesn't have a Past Tense form, but hopefully you can see how that aspect is conveyed through the auxiliary forms ***do / have done***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers to my mind, 'should have done' expresses regret. but my sentence can't express regret because I didn't know at the moment in the past what I was supposed to do. The question is if it's possible to use 'should' in the past, or I need to use 'was supposed to'.

Comment: I think your idea about "expresses regret" just arises from the fact that the Perfect form *I knew what I should **have done*** strongly implies ***...but I didn't actually do it***. There's no particular implication of that with *I knew what I should **do*** - which can reasonably be followed by ***...so I did what they wanted*** OR ***...but I refused to comply.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, that's right